# Need some input on getting this code to run

Tags: c++

I keep getting a error at line 30. saying

```
E0135   namespace "std" has no member "getline"
```

I would appreciate any feed back. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> 
#include <map> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //declaring variables
    string TDU;
    double usage;
    double total_charge;
    int run =1;
    //declare a map to store names of TDU and montly fixed costs in dollars
    map<string, double> monthlycharges; 
    monthlycharges.insert(pair<string, double>("ONCOR", 3.42)); 
    monthlycharges.insert(pair<string, double>("CENTERPOINT ENERGY", 5.47)); 
    monthlycharges.insert(pair<string, double>("AEP TEXAS CENTRAL", 9.00)); 
    monthlycharges.insert(pair<string, double>("AEP TEXAS NORTH", 10.53)); 
    monthlycharges.insert(pair<string, double>("TEXAS - NEW MEXICO POWER", 7.85)); 
    
    //declare a map to store names of TDU and usage costs in cents
    map<string, double> kwhcharges; 
    kwhcharges.insert(pair<string, double>("ONCOR", 3.8447)); 
    kwhcharges.insert(pair<string, double>("CENTERPOINT ENERGY", 4.03120)); 
    kwhcharges.insert(pair<string, double>("AEP TEXAS CENTRAL", 4.84460)); 
    kwhcharges.insert(pair<string, double>("AEP TEXAS NORTH", 4.01990)); 
    kwhcharges.insert(pair<string, double>("TEXAS - NEW MEXICO POWER", 4.83210)); 
   
    while(run==1){
    cout<<"Enter the name of TDU: "<<endl;
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, TDU);
    cout<<"Enter the usage in kWh used: "<<endl;
    cin>> usage;
    //declare iterator of maps
    map<string, double>::iterator it_monthlycharges; 
    map<string, double>::iterator it_kwhcharges; 
    //use the find function of map to get the pointer to correct entry according to key 'TDU'
    it_monthlycharges = monthlycharges.find(TDU); 
    it_kwhcharges = kwhcharges.find(TDU); 
    //calculate the charges
    total_charge =it_monthlycharges->second + (it_kwhcharges->second*0.01*usage);
    //print the final output
    cout<<"TDU Delivery charges for "<<TDU<<" : "<<total_charge<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 1 to calculate bill for another month, 0 to exit"<<endl;
    cin>>run;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::getline` is part of the header `<string>`, which you didn't include.

Comment: Ok Ill rework this and include #include <string>.  I thought using namespace std; was the problem, since I was getting results that this is bad to use.I'll working on the name space issue also haha.

Thank you.

Comment: After adding #include <string> I am getting this error

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Users\Owner\source\repos\TDU attamp_t\Debug\TDU attamp_t.exe
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xtree
Line: 182

Expression: cannot dereference end map/set iterator

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)


Abort   Retry   Ignore

Comment: I just tried the code using http://cpp.sh/ and it ran. It might be my Visual studios? AM I missing a setting haha? Not sure what is going on here. Thanks.

Comment: No, dereferencing the end-iterator (like obtained from `monthlycharges.end()`) causes undefined behaviour. It's perfectly fine for it to run on one platform and crash on another. `monthlycharges.find(TDU);` can also return the end-iterator, which would indicate that `TDU` was not found, you need to check for this case.